# Elasticsearch object mapping for tried to parse field [] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

In AWS Elasticseach, I created an index using python and [Elasticsearch library](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/) using the following line of code:

```
es.indices.create(TABLE_NAME, body='{"settings": { "index.mapping.coerce": true } }', request_timeout=100)
```

Then I inserted some documents in my index using [bulk](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk).

```
helpers.bulk(es, action, request_timeout=500)
```

Later when I tried to insert more documents it gave me this error:

**Elasticsearch object mapping for tried to parse field [] as object, but found a concrete value**

The only difference is that I changed the type of inserted value (from float to string). Is that the cause of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this error is due to the change of type from float to string.

So, you can either insert a float value or you can [delete the index](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.13.2/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete) using the following command and insert all the values again.

```
es.indices.delete(index=TABLE_NAME)
```

NOTE: Do not use this command if you do not have the old documents. This command will permanently delete the full index along with all the documents in it.